# Can i find the seed needed to change the first number to the second number?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography

I have a problem with a program that gives me a random number and i have to guess the next number. I need to guess 10 correct in a row then i'll get to the flag

I know the next number is constant and i have a script that found that if certain number appears first, the second correct number will be the same.

Everytime i solve a number. they will give me a new number to guess.
for example

```
here's my number: 19
Guess my number => 68
Welldone!
---
here's my second number: 58
Guess my number => 59
Welldone!
---
here's my third number: 34
Guess my number => 86
Wrong number!
```

rules:
numbers are 1 to 100 inclusive
i found out that if:

> Generated first number  -  correct second number
>
> 19 - 68 - ? - ? - ...
>
> 17 - 53 - ? - ? - ...
>
> 85 - 20 - ? - ? - ...
>
> 90 - 21 - ? - ? - ...
>
> 11 - 46 - ? - ? - ...

Please guide me and point me in the right direction

I have tried xor-ing the numbers, converting to hex/dec then finding a pattern to no avail

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the difference between seed and internal-state of a PRNG. Also: this task is always dependent on the underlying PRNG. If it's one designed for cryptography, there is nothing you can do (in feasible time).

Comment: @sascha thanks for your reply. The next number will always be the same if a certain number comes out. is it possible to predict the next number by finding out the method of getting the second number by using the first number and the seed?

Comment: If the next number is fully dependent on the number before (internal-state is super-tiny; not very practical), then you just need to sample until you saw each pairing (your range is also super-tiny). I don't see the problem here. This also looks more like hashing, than random-numbers. If your rule in the first sentence is true, read up hashing algorithms and maybe you find some ideas (if these are still needed). For everything else it's needed that you post much more information (more formal description of the environment; you got x observations; or you can sample as often as you like...).

Comment: @sascha Actually i got the rules mixed up, everytime i solve a number. they will give me a new number to guess.

Comment: Well... we still don't know the environment. If they use a cryptoPRNG, you can tackle this for decades.

Comment: @sascha i have updated the question. will i be able to brute force this if i find the combination for all 100 numbers and it's subsequent values?

Comment: No. Not if they have some internal-state which is more than the last number (and specifically designed to be non-predictable). Please... Read up a bit on the basics of random-number generators. It's very likely that you got more information,. which you are not sharing or someone want's you to do the hard work: checking for common PRNG-designs.